# Remove cases where region specified incorrrectly

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I am using `MeshPrimitives` to get a list of 3D components of a Mesh Region. Within that list, I normally get some incorrectly specified regions, such as

```
Tetrahedron[{{1.9, 0.45, 2.}, {1.8, 0.3, 2.}, {1.8, 0.6, 2.}, {1.6, 0.5, 2.}}]
```

This is, of course, incorrectly specified because all the points are are in the same Z-plane and thus a function like `RegionCentroid` will fail. I would like to find a way to use `DeleteCases` or something similar to remove all the incorrectly specified regions in my list, but I don't know how make a pattern for it. Any suggestions? Is there a way to remove items that throw an error when a certain function is applied?

Comment: `Select[list, RegionQ]`?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I didn't know RegionQ existed. Thanks!

Comment: Ben, if that solves your problem, would you consider posting an expanded version of @ilian's comment as an answer to your question, maybe with an example of data and usage too? Answering your own question is encouraged here on stackexchange, and having a complete answer makes a question that much more valuable to future users with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use `RegionQ`, a simple solution suggested by ilian. `RegionQ` is a function that takes a region as an argument and returns whether it is a valid region. Here is how I used it:

```
regCells = Select[MeshPrimitives[DiscretizedRegion, 3], RegionQ];
```

This only keeps the regions returned by `MeshPrimitives` which are valid regions, which allows region-based functions to be applied to the list `regCells` without throwing errors.